# How to use universal reference in C++11

Tags: c++11

We would like to combine the following 2 map_at() functions into one, using universal reference T&&. Could somebody help?

```
template<typename T> // version const
const typename T::mapped_type& map_at(const T& m, const typename T::key_type& key)
{
    if (const auto& iter = m.find(key); iter != m.cend()) {
        return iter->second;
    }
    else {
        throw std::exception("blah");
    }
}

template<typename T> // version non-const
typename T::mapped_type& map_at(T& m, const typename T::key_type& key)
{
    if (const auto& iter = m.find(key); iter != m.cend()) {
        return iter->second;
    }
    else {
        throw std::exception("blah");
    }
}

int main()
{
    using T = std::map<int, float>;
    T t;
    const T ct;

    try {
        map_at(ct, 3); // calls version const
    }
    catch (...){}

    try {
        map_at(t, 3); // calls version non-const
    }
    catch (...){}
}
```

We tried the following with T&&, but get error

1> ConsoleApplication1.cpp(557,9): error C2672: 'map_at': no matching overloaded function found

```
template<typename T> // version T&&
typename T::mapped_type&& map_at(T&& m, const typename T::key_type& key)
{
    if (const auto& iter = m.find(key); iter != m.cend()) {
        return iter->second;
    }
    else {
        throw std::exception("blah");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one is line 557?

Comment: `T` is being deduced as either `map&` or `map&&` (which is kind of the point of universal references). Either way, `T::mapped_type` and `T::key_type` is ill-formed, since `T` is not a class type.  You can get past that by writing e.g. `std::remove_reference_t<T>::mapped_type&&`. But then you have another problem - `std::remove_reference_t<T>::mapped_type&&` is not a universal reference, it's an honest rvalue reference, and it can't bind to an lvalue.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid two functions. But you can implement the second in terms of the first, [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/n9TTe1aKa)

Comment: the problem is that you're trying to infer nested types from T... but in your case T is deduced as a reference type and doesn't have nested ones, substitution fails.